# XML in curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am calling an API using CURL.
When I run it directly in browser or via ajax request it runs well and gives xml output.The Api am calling stores the xml in a database table and would only then work well.
However when I call it via PHP curl their table is not getting updated.

The code am doing it with PHP curl is

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Sample URL :  http://example.com/code=x05a&businessKeyValue=8519ada0-9e2f-e265-8698-5b6145af9704&entity=funded_program_concession&parameters=fpc_funded_program_concession_id%7C8519ada0-9e2f-e265-8698-5b6145af9704&parameters=fps_funded_program_subsidy_id%7Cf320f2d9-7c6a-0b56-2940-5b61147a0f3d

If I open this link which opens it in browser, it works good, but if I run it via curl the API is not receiving xml content.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you adding `Accept: application/json`? This is a hint to the server that you want JSON back, and won't accept anything else.

Comment: Thanks iainn, I removed it now but am still not getting the expected output on the api's table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$api='http://example.com/code=x05a&businessKeyValue=8519ada0-9e2f-e265-8698-5b6145af9704&entity=funded_program_concession&parameters=fpc_funded_program_concession_id%7C8519ada0-9e2f-e265-8698-5b6145af9704&parameters=fps_funded_program_subsidy_id%7Cf320f2d9-7c6a-0b56-2940-5b61147a0f3d';

$ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();//put your headers only if you need them
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $result= curl_exec($ch);

    return $result;
```

This should work for you. Inside your headers array make sure you put the headers you need and not extra. This is a simple curl, get call so i guess the above code will work without any trouble.

If you want to accept xml then you can got for `Accept:application/xml` or `Accept:application/xhtml+xml`

If the above methods don't work provide us with your error.

```
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
```

Add the above line as a breaking point in your code and see what's the error.

Comment: Thanks Prince, but am not getting an error,curl call works fine but the api then stores the parameters I send as xml Eg :<table>
  <row fpc_funded_program_concession_id="8519ada0-9e2f-e265-8698-5b6145af9704" fps_funded_program_subsidy_id="f320f2d9-7c6a-0b56-2940-5b61147a0f3d" />
</table>

Comment: It works fine when I call it directly hitting in browser but when I call it with curl this value is not getting updated, though the logs on api server shows it got fired